# Find/Replace Numbers with itself minus some fixed value

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex, replace

So I have a SQL script to insert a ton  of rows (140,000+) into a database table. Each row has one or more columns with a numeric value in it. I need to replace each of those numbers with the number minus some offset (see example below). Anyone know a quick and easy way to do it or a program to do it? Basically I'd like to just specify what the offset is and have it iterate through the file, finding all numbers and subtracting the offset from each number.

Any and all help (or a pointer in the right direction) is greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Sample rows:

```
insert into failurelist (failurelist,failurecode,parent,type,orgid) values (6284, 'ABSRBR', null, null, 'ABC');
insert into failurelist (failurelist,failurecode,parent,type,orgid) values (6285, 'SEIZED', '6284', 'PROBLEM', 'ABC');
insert into failurelist (failurelist,failurecode,parent,type,orgid) values (6286, 'ABSRB-PERF', '6285', 'CAUSE', 'ABC');
```

Those are the first 3 rows of the script. For this script, I'd want to subtract 6283 (so that they were numbered starting at 1 instead of 6284). Note that some numeric values are in single quotes '  ' while others are not.

Comment: Why don't you just not insert that column at all, then create it afterwards assigning it primary_key and auto_increment? Or run an update over your table afterwards subtracting 6283 from that column (you'll still have to reset your auto_increment value though, or new rows will be big)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

wouldldnt you just write something like this:

```
  Update failurelist set failurelist = failurelist - 6283
```

Comment: Wow...I wasn't even thinking about updating it after that fact! DUH! That's what happens when you've been starting at SQL scripts too long in one day! Thanks for the answer!

Comment: No problem! Mazel tov

Answer (score 0):

The fact that the 'parent' column seems to be a unary relationship is a little confusing to me. If the Primary key column is an integer, why would the parent column be represented as a string. If they were both integers, you could just:

```
UPDATE failurelist 
SET failurelist = failurelist - 6283,
   parent = parent - 6283
```

In its current form you'll need to do something like this:

```
DECLARE @failurelist TABLE
(
failurelist     INT,
failurecode     varchar(20),
parent          varchar(20),
type            varchar(20),
orgid           varchar(20)
)

insert into @failurelist (failurelist,failurecode,parent,type,orgid) values (6284, 'ABSRBR', null, null, 'ABC');
insert into @failurelist (failurelist,failurecode,parent,type,orgid) values (6285, 'SEIZED', '6284', 'PROBLEM', 'ABC');
insert into @failurelist (failurelist,failurecode,parent,type,orgid) values (6286, 'ABSRB-PERF', '6285', 'CAUSE', 'ABC');

UPDATE @failurelist 
SET failurelist = failurelist - 6283,
    parent      = CAST(CAST(parent AS INT) -6283 AS varchar(20))
```

Now the table variable @failurelist contains the desired results. You just have to populate the actual table with the results from the Table Variable like so

```
INSERT INTO failurelist
  SELECT * FROM @failurelist
```

Comment: Although the numbers for the parent column are in single quotes, it inserted them as INTs (since the column was INT). I believe it warned me that it would be converting data types, but it inserted OK and I was able to run the UPDATE script and  correct them all. Thanks for the help though!